# Creating a column chart in Excel that ignores blank cells

Tags: excel, charts

I have a data table like below:

[image]

I need to generate a column chart from it. But when I generate a column chart, it gives an empty space between columns because of the empty cell values.

[image]

How can I fix it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's a clustered column chart, so each series has an allocated space in each cluster of the chart. If a series has no value for a data point, then the space allocated for that data point will stay empty.

To do what you describe you would have to move all data into one column, add a few empty rows to delineate clusters, plot the whole thing as one series and then manually format each data point to have the fill you want it to have.

From a data visualisation point of view this would be totally wrong, though.